# Visual Studio 2022 MAUI - apk does not install on my phone

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui

I am currently developing an application which appears fine in the Android emulator but I cannot install it on my phone (Xiaomi mi8), it gives an error saying  "App not installed".
I tried on several phones with the same result.

could someone give me some ideas about what to do?

thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you trying to install it?  What do the device logs show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be anything.

Common mistake is not signing the apk file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli

The article is quite long, so if you have problems somewhere, ask.

Edit,
Some people swear this is the right way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-ad-hoc

However, I like to make a single bat file that I can call from anywhere. Your choice...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the ad-hoc path and it worked seamless

Comment: I just created a new project and the same ad-hoc process does not seem to work. I signed the apk , movde the apk to my google drive and authorized the drive app to install unknown source, but the installation keeps failing. any other suggestion about what could be happening?

Comment: @YaKs it says again "app not installed" and nothing more?

Comment: no more messages shown via standard installation, execution of apk from file explorer. 
But, I tried the installation from adb command and it was successful.
adb install -r com.cortisoft.wisejam.apk
Performing Streamed Install
Success
I dont understand why, any idea?

Comment: @YaKs Check your versions, the one in the apk should be equal or higher than the installed. Check your installed packages, there should be no other package with the same name. Check your certificate, it should be the same if you have installed app. I would start by installing 3rd party APK the way you try to install your own. If it fails - its not your APK problem, if it installs without problem, I would try to rebuild it, checking all above. It is worth trying also installing it on another device.

Answer (score 0):

.net maui is very sensitive. I had the same issue. To resolve it, I have redo the signing process more than one time.