Maui Android APK won't install
I have gotten an app to a point I want to give it to a few friends to help me test it and get feedback, and I am having some issues with it being able to be installed. With my phone, I understand why it won't install, I have Android 13, and when I built the app, I targeted 14. Although, when I tested on an emulator that was 13 it worked fine, but ok, that still makes sense to a degree. Anyhow, I pass it to a friend who has Android 14, and he gets the same error when trying to install it - App not installed as app not compatible with your phone. When I set it up, the project has 14 targeted with the lowest targeted version being 5. It works on an emulator (through debugging) on 13 and 14. Does anyone know of a way to find out why it's not installing?
Built, compiled and tested on Android emulators, then tried to install on phones to test.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:compileSdkVersion="34"
    android:compileSdkVersionCodename="14"
    package="com.companyname.mu"
    platformBuildVersionCode="34"
    platformBuildVersionName="14">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="34" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.companyname.mu.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="0x2" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.companyname.mu.DYNAMIC_RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED_PERMISSION" />

    <application
        android:label="MU"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f0d0000"
        android:name="crc64ff115ceda4dc7f22.MainApplication"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:roundIcon="@ref/0x7f0d0003"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory">

        <activity
            android:theme="@ref/0x7f100138"
            android:name="crc64ff115ceda4dc7f22.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="0x1f80">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="crc6468b6408a11370c2f.WebAuthenticatorIntermediateActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="0x480" />

        <provider
            android:name="microsoft.maui.essentials.fileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.companyname.mu.fileProvider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@ref/0x7f120001" />
        </provider>

        <receiver
            android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver"
            android:name="crc64e53d2f592022988e.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name="crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:configChanges="0x480" />

        <receiver
            android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver"
            android:name="crc640a8d9a12ddbf2cf2.BatteryBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver"
            android:name="crc640a8d9a12ddbf2cf2.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <service
            android:name="crc64396a3fe5f8138e3f.KeepAliveService" />

        <provider
            android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.companyname.mu.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__"
            android:initOrder="1999999999" />

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:authorities="com.companyname.mu.androidx-startup">

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallerInitializer"
                android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.extensions"
            android:required="false" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="androidx.window.sidecar"
            android:required="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.DUMP"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:directBootAware="false">

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.INSTALL_PROFILE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SKIP_FILE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.SAVE_PROFILE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>

                <action
                    android:name="androidx.profileinstaller.action.BENCHMARK_OPERATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>


The minimum and target SDK is not the only property that can prevent app installation. Missing hardware and/or software features can also prevent installation and usage. Analyze the final APK in Android Studio, extract the AndroidManifest.xml and include it in your post.

@Robert: Added the AndroidManifest.xml

Looks pretty clean. Is this the final version decompiled from APK or the one you see in the development IDE? If it is the latter it may be incomplete as every used library can  add entries to it in the compilation process. Anyway if the target phone as adb enabled try to install it via adb install. Then you will see (hopefully) an error message telling you installation does not work.

Yeah, it's the final decompiled from the APK. I'll see what I can manage to work with the adb.

You build it, and you sign it right? You are not trying to deploy unsigned apk?

@H.A.H. honestly, I don't remember if "signing" was something I did or not. I went through the command line for .net to compile it to APK. I just found something on Microsofts site about signing APKs, so I'll go through that. If it's something this simple, it will be just another brick in the wall of mobile development trying to drive me insane! :D

@JoeSchmidt have you created a keystore, that has been used in that command? alias and password? Can you show me the command? I am telling this because unsigned apk wont install.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76756580/visual-studio-2022-maui-apk-does-not-install-on-my-phone/76756735#76756735 The message you get is strange, but it is worth to check it.

@H.A.H. Looking at it, I didn't actually do that, as from what I was able to find about building the apk didn't have that referenced. I have been a Microsoft developer for a quarter century now, and out of everything I've used from the original BASIC language to more recent stuff like Azure SQL and .Net Core, they've always been really good at easy to find documentation. MAUI, however, appears to be the exception to that, as I've struggled at times with stuff that would have been far easier with documentation that was easy to find. Oh well, I'll try this out and will update!

Thanks, @H.A.H. !! That was it! I have it installed on my phone for testing! Woo!

Glad it solved your problem, I will vote to close this, by adding a link to the other question, since the issue turned out to be caused by the same underlying reason. If you bump into other problems, you can open another question. Good luck with your project.
